# Trying to make cavemen and dinosaur battle

Tags: weapons, dinosaurs

I'm trying to make a world with dinosaurs but with cavemen to fight them.

Which prehistoric weapons or ways to hunt are capable to slay the beast, like T-Rex

> The most complete specimen measures up to 12.3 meters (40 feet) in length, though T. rex could grow to lengths of over 12.3 m (40 ft), up to 3.96 m (13 ft) tall at the hips, and according to most modern estimates 8.4 metric tons (9.3 short tons) to 14 metric tons (15.4 short tons) in weight.

What weapons should the cavemen have and what should they do with it.

I am taking neanderthals

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding. It depends what you mean by cavemen. If they are living in the Stone Age, the most likely will be spears with wooden hafts and flint tips. They might have burning brands that they use for exploring the caves and that would scare the dinos. Remember that dinosaurs and humans weren't alive during the same era so yours is definitively a fictional world.  As for language, you can assume that they have words for all the animals they know plus things like mountains and rivers, and can talk about family relationships.

Comment: Same as a mammoth. A cliff and lots of fire.

Comment: This discussion might be helpful: https://www.quora.com/How-did-prehistoric-humans-kill-mammoths

Comment: They made a movie for you : [One Million Years BC](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060782/).  No, not about the time taken for the US government to agree a budget, but the early development of the prehistoric bikini.  Fascinating stuff.  Won't tell you a thing about hunting T-Rex but does have Raquel Welch in very variable amounts of fur. :-)

Comment: Yeah you need to give us a bit more info. What kind of cavemen do you mean? Are you referring to Neanderthals or early members of our species? Were the cavemen teleported to the jurassic period through a temporal anomaly or did a group of time traveling individuals just abducted a cavemen and a number of other creatures from different periods and put them in a zoo mixed together?

Comment: Step 1: use the timemachine that took them to dinosaur time, go to the future, and buy/hire/steal a DeathOTron Autokiller Superbot.

Comment: *'the idea // they were a different 'species' at all may not even meet scientific criteria were they still alive today'* // unless of course any cross-bred offspring were mules or could only back-breed into one of the two parent populations & that last is a little borderline.

Comment: @Pelinore I know they had similar tech and skills and that they mixed genes via breeding with "us". But, as far as I'm aware, they didn't hunt the same, with the Neanderthals sticking to smaller groups and relying more on their stronger build rather than on numbers like us, and didn't stick as much to long ranged weapons, which I'd say can make a big difference when you're hunting a large predator like T-rex. The place is also important because you can't make wooden spears or dig traps in a concrete floor. Also I'd say trees changed a bit since the jurassic period.

Comment: @Pelinore what I'm trying to say is that this question is essentially asking how would a group of hominids (in this case Neanderthals as he clarified) hunt down a T-rex, and when it comes to hunting a big animal that can potentially end you with one attack if you get careless, **everything** is important: from your capabilities, to what you know about the animal, to the location where you'll hunt it, to the strategies you'll make based on those and other factors. So yes, I'd say what group of hominids and where they're hunting the T-Rex are important bits of information to know in this case.

Comment: @ProjectApex hmm . you may actually have something with the trees thing, are our cavemen displaced into an otherwise late Cretaceous environment or are our t-rex displaced into an otherwise Pleistocene environment, the available plants for tools may differ [Googles] // hmm, [there were conifers in the Early Cretaceous](https://www.britannica.com/science/Cretaceous-Period/Terrestrial-life) so maybe not // chasing or luring them (with tasty hominid morsels) into falling into pits or off cliffs is the most likely method to my eye anyway & there are cliffs in both eras :)

Comment: @ProjectApex in short, *everything* is **not** important, anything is only important if there is some pertinent qualitative difference that can be identified in it.

Comment: @Pelinore and the existence of said qualitative differences are precisely why my "terrible comment" was posted. Neanderthals were physically stronger than us, the plants and terrain during the cretaceous period weren't the same as those found in the pleistocene period (we had mammals in the cretasceous period, doesn't mean we could find the exact same mammals in the pleistocene) and the presence of certain landmarks can greatly affect certain strategies (aka why them being in a mostly plane "zoo"  cage would limit available hunting tactics like throwing the animal off a cliff).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123364/discussion-between-projectapex-and-pelinore).

Answer (score 4):

1. Bullfight style.  Individual cavemen run up and throw a spear, then run away.  Well dressed caveman keeps TRex attention during this.  Cavepeople throw flowers.
2. Rodeo style.  A caveman jumps on the TRex and rides it off a cliff, jumping off just in time.
3. Team rodeo.  Many cavemen lasso the TRex from many angles then move it into a deep hole they have prepared in advance.  They throw enemy cavemen in the hole until one of them can kill the TRex with his bare hands, then they make that one their king.
4. Poison apple.  This is the method used by Conan in [Red Nails](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/32759/32759-h/32759-h.htm).  It is one of the best Conan stories!
5. Tame Triceratops.  Those things love to kill TRex and smoking hot barely clad cavepeople ride them.
6. Poison meat.  This is easier than apple because TRex likes to eat meat it finds.  Leave some poison in meat.  Maybe something that makes it act crazy and scare the other TRexes because that would be cool.
7. TRex tipping.  Wait until TRex is asleep then run up and tip it over.  Onto spikes, I guess or it will get back up.  First put down the spikes, quietly. Or wait until it is sleeping next to spikes.
8. Lightning.  Draw TRex onto golf course during lightning storm.  This might not work on the first try.
9. Age.  Wait for old TRex to die of lumbago then claim credit.
10. Rock on head.  Drop rock off cliff on head of TRex.  This method gets no style points because that is just such a caveman thing to do.

Comment: Willk, 8 and 9 are not feasible for cavepeople! How would they have golf courses and credit back then?!

Comment: @Alendyias - my poor schemes are crushed by your brutal logic.  I guess there are just 8 ideas.

Comment: Willk, it's okay, you can still make it work. Maybe sticking a javelin in a dinosaur where it can't reach and waiting for the javelin to get struck by lightning, or trapping the dinosaur somewhere and waiting for it to die of old age?

Comment: "then they make that one their king" - what is left of it, lol))

Comment: Only two really plausible methods I can think of with something that size & you seem to have eschewed them both // 1. chase or lure it off a cliff (or into a pit-trap if no handy cliff nearby) 2. & the high risk tangle it's legs bolas style tactic with a long rope held either end by 2 men (because a real bolas is too small & a giant one is silly) laying in wait as a 3rd lures it to them, preferably at full charge, with luck it'll break its neck in the fall, if not should do enough damage they can finish at their leisure, // for some reason I don't think you're taking this seriously? ;))

Comment: ahh @Pelinore. your #1 has been awesomed up and is my#2, and your #2 is my #3 because one man's silly is another man's rocking rex-butt-ricking dino capture scene.  It all has to do with the backing track you use.